# Saving movement/path to database

Tags: path, move

I am creating a football simulation game and I would like to make a 2D view of match. My match is 90 minutes long and there are 22 players on the field. How could I save a movements/path for players so that it wouldn't take lots of space. I know I could save it something like

```
Minute: min, 
Player: id, 
X: xCoord, 
Y: yCoord
```

and then just move objects with jQuery from point A to point B, but I am sure it isn't the best solution, because it would require lots of space and database entries.
I am using MongoDB, but all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Anyone? :( Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do the players move? They move a little in each step of the main loop? Or they go in long straight lines and then make sudden turns and go in other straight lines? In the first case you would probably need to save each milisecond or so (each step of the main loop), or you could save their positions every ten steps or every second, etc. And the replay could interpolate the saved points (thought the replay would look "gross" like that, it could save a lot of space in your db). In the second case (straight lines), you could just save the points where the players turn in another direction. In this case you'll save their position, angle and speed (along with time, obviously).

The first table could be (the intervals could be more than 1ms, depending on the power of the machine):

```
PLAYER  TIME(ms)  X  Y
   1       0      0  0
   1       1      0  2
   1       2      0  4
   1       3      0  7
   1       4      0 10
   1       5      4 13
```

While the second table would be:

```
PLAYER  TIME(ms)  X  Y  Dir  Speed
   1       0      0  0   90    2
   1       2      0  4   90    3
   1       4      0 10   60    5
```

or something like that. Dir is the direction in degrees. Hope that helps!